# Looking for the fastest way to sort a list of 2000 items long consisting of three different values in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, sorting

Basically the program will be given a list of items and they have to be sorted into three different "bins." Think of it as if you were sorting three colors of marbles. The items are all of type char.
thanks for the help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: Funny, I have the _exact same problem_. I think I know this guy. Yes, it's homework, and yes, we're allowed to use the internet for help. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 11):

This isn’t really a classical “sorting” problem … since there are only a fixed number of possible values, this is known as a *partitioning* problem and there exists an efficient solution for the three-ways partition known as the [Dutch flag sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem), first proposed by Edsger Dijkstra.

This algorithm runs in O(*n*) and needs only a single pass over the array.

The algorithm can also be found rather trivially by developing the loop invariant.

Comment: +1 for making an excellent guess at what is really being asked for.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is perfect for bucket sort: Basically create a list of 256 int counts and each time you encounter a value in your list, increment the count for that value. Then iterate over the counts to put them back in order. This is O(n).

Comment: This is by far the easiest, and almost certainly the fastest, solution. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be two calls to [partition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/):

```
vector<char> v(2000);
...
std::partition(
    std::partition(
        v.begin(),
        v.end(),
        function_to_match_first_value()),
    v3.end(),
    function_to_match_second_value());
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at this? http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/few-unique-keys

Comment: Hadn't seen that one before. Great resource.

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort`. Then an `O(n)` search for boundaries.